# jQuery mobile dynamic page theme swatch doesn't work correctly?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, themes

First of all, I apologize for my bad English. 
I'm trying to dynamically change the page theme with the function found in the jQuery mobile API documentation.

The function is like this:

```
$('[data-role="page"]').page( 'option', 'theme', 'b' );
```

If I run this function several times with different swatch themes, it adds the page CSS class theme for each swatch instead of switching it.

Example:

- **I load the page with default theme.**
- It adds  in the page class:

  `ui-page-theme-a`
- **Then I execute:**

  `$('[data-role="page"]).page( 'option', 'theme', 'b' );`
- It adds:

  `ui-page-theme-b`
- And removes:

  `ui-page-theme-a`
- **Then I execute:**

  `$('[data-role="page"]).page( 'option', 'theme', 'a' );`
- It adds:

  `ui-page-theme-a`
- But does not remove:

  `ui-page-theme-b`

I don't know if this is the normal behavior (or happen only in my case) so I ask for clarification on this and in case this is the normal use, how to "emulate" a switch behavior? ( JQuery mobile 1.4.5)

Thanks.

Comment: if you view the demo source code -- https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/theme-default/ -- its done this way  ($( "#pageid" ).removeClass( "ui-page-theme-a ui-page-theme-b" ).addClass( "ui-page-theme-" + themeClass );) -- themeClass is either a or b -- you need to do this for other elements in the page if they dont pick up the change

Comment: @ Tasos Thanks man. I think this isn't an elegant solution. At least not for dinamically generated themes. I found just now that if i use the same function type for the toolbars (header and footer) the switch behavior work well. So i think it could only be a problem in Page version function.

Comment: I founed that the $('[data-role="panel"]').panel( 'option', 'theme', 'b' ); version do not work at all.

Comment: well theres another way of doing it and i think its much better  -- have specific  dark.css, light.css etc files and change them dynamically. this is what i used to do -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19844545/replacing-css-file-on-the-fly-and-apply-the-new-style-to-the-page

Comment: Are you using both jquery ui and jquery mobile..?

Comment: @TJ no i using only jquery mobile 1.4.5

Comment: @Tungsteno Then please don't tag it. Only add relevant tags...