# Replace div content when selecting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

I'm working on palette board project and struggling when changing to different theme.

Initial page will have ***Warm*** color palette, but I want to change this after clicking ***All*** theme.

Users will have options to choose different theme if you tap the dropdown menu just like the image I posted.

Below you will find images that I imagine.

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

body {
  margin:0;
  color: #FFF;
}

.board {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.board-nav-indicator {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:75px;
  height:75px;
  /*background-color:red;*/
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, #FF512F, #DD2476);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left top, #FF512F, #DD2476);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom right, #FF512F, #DD2476);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, #FF512F, #DD2476);
  background-image: linear-gradient(bottom right, #FF512F, #DD2476);
  transition:all 0.3s;
  transform:translateX(0);
  z-index:1;
}
[data-page='0'] .board-nav-indicator {
  transform:translateX(0);
}
[data-page='1'] .board-nav-indicator {
  transform:translateX(100%);
}
[data-page='2'] .board-nav-indicator {
  transform:translateX(200%);
}

.board-nav-buttons {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position:relative;
  z-index:2;
}

.board-pages {
  position:absolute;
  top:75px;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:calc(100% - 75px);
  overflow:hidden;
}
.board-page {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  transition:all 0.4s;
  transform:translateX(0);
  overflow:auto;
  background-color: #262931;
}

.grid-row-theme .grid-item-theme {
  max-width: 130px;
}

#align-left {
  float: left;
  color: #747474;
}

#align-right {
  float: right;
  color: #9CC8E3;
}

.grid-item {
  flex:0 1 25%;
  padding:6px;
}

.grid-item-theme {
  flex:0 1 25%;
  padding:6px;
}

.grid-row {
  overflow-x:auto;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

.grid-row .grid-item {
  display:inline-block;
  max-width:110px;
}

.grid-item-content {
  text-align:left;
  font-family: "mr-eaves-modern";
  font-size:0.3rem;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}


.pick-palette img{
  border: 3px solid #FFF;
}

#dropdown-menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2% 0 6% 0;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal-inside {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content-theme {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 10% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius:4px 4px 4px 4px;
    width: 70%;
    height: 430px;

}

/* The Close Button */
.close-theme {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); /* Black w/ opacity */
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close-theme:hover,
.close-theme:focus {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.theme-list-dropdown {
  color: #BDBEC1;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "mr-eaves-modern";
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.theme-list-name {
  padding: 20.5px;
}

#all-theme-list-name {
  margin-top: -5px;
}

#warm-theme-list-name {
  color: #262931;
/*  background-color: #EEEEEF;*/
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Omnibag Project</title>
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
</head>
<body> 

<div class="board-pages">

      <div class="board-page">

        <div class="grid-item-theme" id="dropdown-menu"><div id="themeBtn" class="theme-warm">Warm</div><i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_down</i></div>
        
        
          <!-- The Modal -->
          <div id="myModal" class="modal-inside">
            <span class="close-theme">&times;</span>

            <div class="modal-content-theme">
              <div class="theme-list-dropdown">
                <div class="theme-list-name" id="all-theme-list-name">All</div>
                <div class="theme-list-name" id="">Bright</div>
                <div class="theme-list-name">Dark</div>
                <div class="theme-list-name" id="warm-theme-list-name">Warm</div>
                <div class="theme-list-name">Cool</div>
                <div class="theme-list-name">Pastel</div>
                <div class="theme-list-name">Neon</div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
          <!-- End: The Modal -->
        
        

        <div class="trending-above-palette">
          <div class="grid-item-theme" id="align-left">Trending</div>
          <div class="grid-item-theme" id="align-right">See all</div>
          <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        </div>   

        <div class="grid-row">
          <div class="grid-item grid-beige">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />   
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Beige
              <!-- <i class="material-icons more-icon">more_horiz</i> -->
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-camel">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Camel
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-salmon">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Salmon Pink
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-navajo">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Navajo White
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-niagara">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Niagara
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-primrose">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Primrose
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-lapis">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Lapis Blue
            </div>
          </div>


        </div>
        




        </div>
      </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://use.typekit.net/hoc0zbs.js"></script>
  <script>try{Typekit.load({ async: true });}catch(e){}</script>

  <script>

    $(".board-pages .grid-item").on("click",function(){
      $(this).parents('.board-page').find('.pick-palette').removeClass("pick-palette");
    $(this).addClass( "pick-palette" );
    });

    $(".board-pages .grid-item-pattern-board").on("click",function(){
      $(this).parents('.board-page').find('.pick-palette').removeClass("pick-palette");
    $(this).addClass( "pick-palette" );
    });
 

  </script>
  
  <script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
// var btn = document.getElementById("themeBtn");
var btn = document.getElementById("themeBtn");
// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close-theme")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}   
</script>
```

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

it can be implemented by using Jquery click and addClass.

- https://api.jquery.com/click/
- https://api.jquery.com/addclass/
- http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

after clicking modal item, the written jquery should add or change top div's class.

like

```
<div class'board-pages [theme]'>
... content
</div>
```

[theme] and its children's css should be defined as well.

or this solution could be another option

[Replacing css file on the fly (and apply the new style to the page)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19844545/replacing-css-file-on-the-fly-and-apply-the-new-style-to-the-page)