# create switch for changing theme intead of browser page style html

Tags: html, css, web, browser

I added a theme in my HTML page by:

```
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" href="css/dark.css" title="dark">
```

this creates an option to switch theme from view>style in browser as it is expected to. I want to create a switch in the page itself for changing the theme. `<button>Switch Theme</button>`will create a button but how do I make it switch theme?

Comment: Which browsers have that option?

Comment: Use javascript to bind a click event to the button, on click have the function toggle a `body` class, e.g `<body class="dark/light">` - use this class as a base selector for applicable theme styles, e.g: `.dark a {color: white;}` and `.light a {color: black;}`, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing css file on the fly (and apply the new style to the page)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19844545/replacing-css-file-on-the-fly-and-apply-the-new-style-to-the-page)

Answer (score 4):

You should trigger a change in the `href` attribute of the `<link>` tag on the click of the button, as demonstrated:

**HTML**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dark.css" id="theme">
<button id="switch">Switch Theme</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
document.getElementById('switch').onclick = function() {
  if (document.getElementById('theme').href == "dark.css") {
    document.getElementById('theme').href = "light.css";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('theme').href = "dark.css";
  }
};
```

Now, the `dark.css` and `light.css` would contain different styles for your elements for both the themes respectively. For example:

***dark.css***

```
body{
    background: #000;
}
```

***light.css***

```
body{
    background: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is very simple you need to bind the click to function and call it:

[Replacing css file on the fly (and apply the new style to the page)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19844545/replacing-css-file-on-the-fly-and-apply-the-new-style-to-the-page)

Comment: i guess it's better to flag as duplicate than to put a reference for another question as an answer