# Change / toggle web page theme with a button

Tags: javascript, html, django, bootswatch

Trying various answers on "*toggle theme with button*", I have code, but it is not working

- from bootstrap 4, bootswatch themes 'flatly' and 'darkly' have been selected, since I want to offer user of my web page option to select his/her favorite theme
- I have put complete 'flatly.min.css' and 'darkly.min.css' into my static files folder (django project), and renamed them to 'light.css' and 'dark.css'
- I tried various answers from stack exchange, and currently I use this one:
  [create switch for changing theme intead of browser page style html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48241165/create-switch-for-changing-theme-intead-of-browser-page-style-html)

My base.html:

```
    <head>
      <!-- Required meta tags -->
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    ...

      {% include 'base/css.html' %}

      {% block base_head %}
      {% endblock %}
    </head>

    <body>
    ...
      {% include 'base/js.html' %}

      {% block javascript %}
      {% endblock %}
    </body>
```

My css.html:

```
    <!-- custom styling -->
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="{% static 'css/base.css' %}">
    <!-- light styling  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet alternate"
          id="theme"
          href="{% static 'css/light.css' %}">
    <!-- dark styling  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet alternate"
          id="theme"
          href="{% static 'css/dark.css' %}">
```

When I use only 'css/dark.css' (no 'css/light.css' link is declared), I get my page to render dark; if I change to 'css/light.css' (no 'css/dark.css' is declared), page renders light theme.

My js.html:

```
   ...

    <script src="{% static 'js/ecommerce.sales.js' %}"></script>
    <!-- toggle theme js -->
    <script src="{% static 'js/toggle_theme.js' %}"></script>
```

toggle_theme.js says:

```
    console.log('now what') // works at django runserver first run
    document.getElementById('toggle-theme').onClick = function() {
      console.log('js works'); // not working, js is not run on click
      if (document.getElementById('theme').href == "{% static 'css/dark.css' %}") {
        document.getElementById('theme').href = "{% static 'css/light.css' %}";
      } else {
        document.getElementById('theme').href = "{% static 'css/dark.css' %}";
      }
    }
```

The button I want to use in the navbar:

```
          <!-- todo: toggle theme -->
          <div class="nav-item mx-auto my-auto">
            <!-- href="#" -->
            <!-- <a class="nav-link dark-theme" -->
            <a class="nav-link"
               id="toggle-theme"
               title="toggle theme">
              <!-- id="toggle-theme" -->
              <i class="fas fa-lg fa-square"
                 aria-hidden="true">
                <!-- <script src="{% static 'js/toggle_theme.js' %}"></script> -->
              </i> </a>
          </div>
```

I did usual django stuff, 'python manage.py collectstatic' and Ctrl-F5 to refresh the development browser. What am I missing here?

Thank you for your help

EDIT:
Although above link to "*Toggle between two stylesheets*" did solved my issue, it is not complete, because on refresh the theme is set back to default theme. My complete solution is (dark is my default theme):

```
if (document.getElementById('theme')) {
  if (localStorage) {
    // console.log('storidge');
    if (!localStorage.getItem('theme')) {
      localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark');
    } else {
      if (localStorage.getItem('theme') == 'dark') {
        $("link[id='theme']").attr('href', '/static/css/dark.css');
      } else if (localStorage.getItem('theme') == 'light') {
        $("link[id='theme']").attr('href', '/static/css/light.css');
      }
    }
  }
}

$('#toggle-theme').click(function() {
  if ($("link[id='theme']").attr('href') == '/static/css/dark.css') {
    $("link[id='theme']").attr('href', '/static/css/light.css');
    localStorage.setItem('theme', 'light');
    console.log('changed to light.css');
  } else {
    $("link[id='theme']").attr('href', '/static/css/dark.css');
    localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark');
    console.log('changed to dark.css');
  }
});
```

I do experience some page twinkling at refresh (F5), if light theme is set, but I will have to live with this for now. Dark theme works without twinkling.

Best regards,

Simon
S love nia

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing `document.getElementById('toggle-theme').onClick = function() {` to `document.getElementById('toggle-theme').onclick = function() {`?

No guarantee that's the only issue, but onclick should be all lower case, and if the initial click isn't being recognized that might be your problem.

Comment: Yes, I have, lol, half an hour before I saw this answer. Thank you anyway. Now that button works, I am following the console.log output. Inspecting my web page, I get an error: GET http://localhost:8000/%7B%%20static%20'dark.css'%20%%7D net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found). It seems I toggle_theme.js is not finding my dark.css. Originally I had "{% static 'css/dark.css' %}", changed to "... 'dark.css'...", not working. I am checking now on SO how to call my (django) static files from javascript.

Comment: Ah, sorry I didn't notice that earlier. Django templating has that issue in JS files, but if you move the click event to the HTML file in a <script> tag, do you have the same issue?
Alternately, you could use <script> to declare a variable that stores the static path as a string, then call that variable in your external scripts.

Comment: I did tried <script> var dark_ = "/static/css/dark.css" var light_=..., and set this as .href = dark_, in toggle_theme.js, but it didn't work. Anyway, I have fixed the code as per my last self-reply. Thx for help. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, when I refresh my page, and view page source, I get:

```
<!-- light styling  -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
      id="theme"
      href="/static/css/light.css">
<!-- dark styling  -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
      id="theme"
      href="/static/css/dark.css">
```

If I inspect elements, I get the same code. Then I click my toggle-button, and view page source, the code stays the same, but when I inspect elements, I get:

```
<!-- light styling  -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
      id="theme"
      href="/static/css/dark.css">
<!-- dark styling  -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
      id="theme"
      href="/static/css/dark.css">
```

Both href are "/static/css/dark.css".
So, the code works, but not as expected. This tells me this is not a code to use. Will continue my search.

Comment: Hi! I am also trying to do such a feature of changing the theme. If I press f5 the site shows itself without CSS at all for 1 to 3 seconds and then gets the styles. However, I do not have the links for all my themes in the HTML. Only a link, and then the logic to toggle it. Did you solve your problem? btw, why do you have 2 stylesheet links with the same id?