# Switching website's theme/css file

Tags: javascript, html, css

for my website, I have two different CSS files. One for showing the website in a dark theme and the other one in a light theme.

Now I would like to let the user switch between the two themes. But I don't know how I could implement this. I would prefer not to create two HTML files, where the only difference is that one has a link tag to the light theme and the other one to the dark theme.

The best solution would be that the user simply clicks on a button and the theme changes without reloading.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

## Edit

Decided to go with [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48796000/1496715) answer. Thanks @void

Comment: I would still suggest a better approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/48796000/1496715

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give your stylesheet link an id..

```
<link rel=stylesheet href=mycss.css id=shtylesheet>
```

Then you can change it with javascript

```
function changeStylesheet(newstylesheet){
    document.getElementById('shtylesheet').setAttribute('href', newstylesheet);
}
```

Then if you wanna do buttons or something

```
<button onclick="changeStylesheet('light.css')">Lights on</button>
<button onclick="changeStylesheet('dark.css')">Lights off</button>
```

Comment: Don't you think using this approach, the style transition could be abrupt. Also, it will take some time to fetch the new CSS file then the user might need to wait before he sees the transition? Check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48796000/1496715

Comment: @void - that probably is a better way to do it, there are a lot of things that could be improved upon with my given approach, it's just the simplest answer i could come up with in 5 minutes.. +1

Comment: yea totally agree...

Answer (score 2):

You can switch the theme on runtime by setting an ID to the link tag, like so:

In your HTML file:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="../light.css" id="theme_css" />
```

JS

```
<button onclick="switchTheme()">Switch Theme</button>

<script>
function switchTheme() {
  var check = document
  .getElementById('theme_css')
  .classList[0] === 'light';

  var element = document.getElementById('theme_css');


  if (check) {
   element.href = '../dark.css';
   element.classList.remove('light')
   element.classList.add('dark');
  } else {
   element.href = '../light.css';
   element.classList.remove('dark')
   element.classList.add('light');
  }

}
</script>
```

---

Update.

I've updated my solution to make it more dynamic. You use one button to toggle button the light and dark theme.

Comment: Great answer, thx. What is the purpose of the `media="all" ` entry ?