# Relative file path not working in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, critical-css

I am trying to make pages load faster by including in-line css for above the fold code. This works for pages held in the root directory, but I have a problem with loading the rest of the CSS file at the end of the pages that are in sub folders (i.e http://example.com/other/index.html).

If the current file is in the root folder the following code works fine:

```
   <script>var cb = function() {
var l = document.createElement('link'); l.rel = 'stylesheet';
l.href = 'css/a1tg2.css';
var h = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; h.parentNode.insertBefore(l, h);
};
var raf = requestAnimationFrame || mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
webkitRequestAnimationFrame || msRequestAnimationFrame;
if (raf) raf(cb);
else window.addEventListener('load', cb);</script>
```

but if the current file is in a sub folder the following code does not work:

```
 <script>var cb = function() {
var l = document.createElement('link'); l.rel = 'stylesheet';
l.href = '../css/a1tg2.css';
var h = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; h.parentNode.insertBefore(l, h);
};
var raf = requestAnimationFrame || mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
webkitRequestAnimationFrame || msRequestAnimationFrame;
if (raf) raf(cb);
else window.addEventListener('load', cb);</script>
```

Also, if I try an absolute path it also does not work:

```
   <script>var cb = function() {
var l = document.createElement('link'); l.rel = 'stylesheet';
l.href = 'http://example.com/css/a1tg2.css';
var h = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; h.parentNode.insertBefore(l, h);
};
var raf = requestAnimationFrame || mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
webkitRequestAnimationFrame || msRequestAnimationFrame;
if (raf) raf(cb);
else window.addEventListener('load', cb);</script>
```

The relative location of the file is correct because if I have the following line in the head of the document:

```
<link href="../css/a1tg2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

It also works fine, but I don't want to use that as it slows down the rendering of the page. I am not proficient with JavaScript, just getting the code required from an on-line critical path CSS generator. Can anyone offer a solution please, as none of the similar questions on this site have a satisfactory answer.

Comment: Try this: href = '/css/a1tg2.css';

Comment: @Grant No, that does not work either

Comment: Are you running this on a web server or file system?

Comment: Acutally you should rethink why you cant use the link attribute in your code. This should normally not slow down your rendering ...

Comment: @Grant on a web server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing css file on the fly (and apply the new style to the page)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19844545/replacing-css-file-on-the-fly-and-apply-the-new-style-to-the-page)

Comment: @lightstalker89 Google Pagespeed insights says: "Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content", which is why I am not using the link attribute :-)

Comment: @lightstalker89. That possible question you cited has no reference to relative paths, therefore this is not a duplicate. My qustion relates to finding out why relative path does not work.

Answer (score 0):

check the link of the html file generated and use a path relative to that page.
For example: If your directory structure is:

```
 - css
    - a1tg2.css
- pages
   - header.php
   - footer.php
- index.php
```

If you are including header.php inside index.php, the relative path of the css file in header.php should be css/a1tg2.css and not ../css/a1tg2.css