# Checkbox JavaScript doesn't change Stylesheet

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a website which can switch to dark mode when user wants to. I made 2 stylesheets 1. style.css and 2. darkstyle.css

To make switching possible, I took the code from:[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Lfv0jqL/) and [DevelopPHP](http://www.developphp.com/video/JavaScript/Change-Style-Sheet-Using-Tutorial-CSS-Swap-Stylesheet) and merged them accordingly to make the following code:

HTML:

```
<head>
<title>Home</title>
<link id="pagestyle" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="changeCSS.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<label for="mode"><input id="mode" type="checkbox"> Dark Mode</label>
...
</body>
```

The JavaScript is

```
$('#mode').change(function(){   
if ($(this).prop('checked'))
{
    document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', "darkstyle.css");
}
else
{
    document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', "style.css");
}

});
```

The code above doesn't work.

PS: I searched a lot about this and found a [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19844545/replacing-css-file-on-the-fly-and-apply-the-new-style-to-the-page) but I can't integrate this answer with a checkbox.

Comment: code is working fine for me.

Comment: Was it able to change CSS stylesheets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your issue might have to do with the location where you're loading your JavaScript files. In general, it's good practice to put your `script` tags at the end of your `body`; here, this is especially important, as you're binding a listener to a DOM object that, when your script is executed, hasn't yet been created. Moreover, it appears that you haven't even loaded the jQuery script at the time your script is executed; without jQuery, your script will fail to run. Try moving your `script` tag to the end of the `body`, and make sure that you've loaded jQuery before your `changeCSS.js` file.

Here's a [working demo](https://repl.it/@aaplmath/stackoverflow-js-stylesheet-switching) of your code with the `script` tags properly placed.

Note, however, that even with this working implementation of your code, there is a significant delay between when the checkbox is clicked and when the style change takes effect. This is an inherent drawback of the approach you're taking (i.e., loading an entirely new CSS file); a more performant approach might be to create a class (e.g., `dark`) that is added to or removed from the body when the checkbox is clicked. In your one CSS file, you could then create two sets of rules: one for elements in the regular, "light" state, and one for elements with the `.dark` class. An example might look like:

```
/* The :not(.dark) is not strictly necessary and is simply added for verbosity */
body:not(.dark) {
  background-color: white;
} 
body:not(.dark) h1 {
  color: black;
}

body.dark {
  background-color: black;
}
body.dark h1 {
  color: white
}
```

With the following JavaScript:

```
$('#mode').change(function () {   
  if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
      $(document.body).addClass('dark')
  } else {
      $(document.body).removeClass('dark')
  }
})
```

Comment out line 13 and uncomment line 15 of `index.html` in the REPL linked above to see a demonstration of this code.

Comment: It works perfectly. Thanks. I'll try the other solution also.

Comment: I have one more problem. After I reload the page, it automatically switches back to light them. In Mozilla the checkbox stays checked but theme is light. Any suggestions? Same code as the question (just added JQuery script and changed position of JavaScript tag)

Comment: I would use `localStorage` (which you can read more about on the [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)) to persist the user's selection. I've updated both scripts on the REPL to save and load values from localStorage—I think they're pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: It worked. I'm indebted. I'm just wondering why doesn't it work on Microsoft edge but MDN says that it (Edge) supports `localStorage` . I think maybe it is incompatible with the JQuery version we're using?

Comment: The issue with Microsoft Edge seems to be that it doesn't support `localStorage` from local files (i.e., those accessed from a `file://` URL). There's an open [issue](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/8816771/) on Microsoft's developer site.