# Use classList.toggle on external CSS

Tags: javascript, css

So I've been messing around with JS, and I wanted to make a dark theme toggle button as seen [here.](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_class.asp)

However, that tutorial only shows how to make it work with the `<style>` tag in HTML, not using an external CSS file.

How could I make it toggle the class `.d_theme` from an external CSS file?

Comment: Please visit help center, take [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search) for related topics on Stackoverflow; if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that an answer to that can be provided.

Comment: Where the class is defined in CSS is completely irrelevant to whether or not you can toggle it in the DOM. Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: _Nikhil suggested_ Search Before asking the question you have many options to change the CSS file

[Replacing css file on the fly (and apply the new style to the page)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19844545/replacing-css-file-on-the-fly-and-apply-the-new-style-to-the-page)

Comment: Please attempt to do something and if it doesn't work, show any errors that occur. The tutorial, in fact, does not dictate where the CSS is stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No difference between external and internal CSS when you use JS to toggle

```js
document.getElementById("chk").addEventListener("change",function() {
  document.getElementById("x").classList.toggle("mystyle",this.checked)
})
```

```css
/* This can be in an external file */
.mystyle {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: coral;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" id="chk">Change theme</label>
<div id="x">Here is some text</div>
```