# div button to change css files

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to program div containers that act as buttons. These have to change the HTML page into different CSS files.
Only a small part of JavaScript is allowed to be part of the project. Do you have an approach how I can do that?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Film</title>
    <link id="pagestyle" rel="stylesheet" href="action.css">
    <link id="pagestyle" rel="stylesheet" href="love.css">
    <link id="pagestyle" rel="stylesheet" href="cartoon.css">
    <link id="pagestyle" rel="stylesheet" href="anime.css">
    <link id="pagestyle" rel="stylesheet" href="children.css">
    <link id="pagestyle" rel="stylesheet" href="western.css">
    <link id="pagestyle" rel="stylesheet" href="scary.css">
    <link id="pagestyle" rel="stylesheet" href="fantasy.css">
    <link id="pagestyle" rel="stylesheet" href="quiet.css">
    <link id="pagestyle" rel="stylesheet" href="nature.css">
    <link id="pagestyle" rel="stylesheet" href="all.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <header>
      <div class="actionBtn"></div>
      <div class="loveBtn"></div>
      <div class="cartoonBtn"></div>
      <div class="animeBtn"></div>
      <div class="childrenBtn"></div>
      <div class="fantasyBtn"></div>
      <div class="natureBtn"></div>
      <div class="quietBtn"></div>
      <div class="scaryBtn"></div>
      <div class="westernBtn"></div>
  </header>
  </body>
  <footer></footer>
</html>
```

Comment: Side note, IDs **must** be unique

Comment: Thats true i delete them

Comment: It seems answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19844545/replacing-css-file-on-the-fly-and-apply-the-new-style-to-the-page

Comment: Yes. It answers part of my job. But I don't know how to turn div elements into buttons and insert an image