# How do I disable a <link> element on page load?

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I want to disable a stylesheet on page load with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="..." disabled>
```

This works well in all browsers but Firefox, though it works when I disable it with:

```
var stylesheet = document.querySelector('link');
stylesheet.disabled = true;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried the various dom ready events like `DOMContentLoaded`?

Comment: @PatrickEvans, no, but that's a very good idea. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this explains it a bit better https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link#Non-standard_attributes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firefox not adhering to \`disabled\` stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18237591/firefox-not-adhering-to-disabled-stylesheet)